# Setting ng-checked doesn't allow unchecking?

Tags: angularjs

I set the `ng-checked` directive in the Create page (used in edit too) based on data from the database. but the problem is that I can't uncheck it, so I can't edit the data:

```
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="25" flex="45" content-layout-align="center start" ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
                    <md-checkbox class="chbox" aria-label="tab.name" checklist-model="entity.tabs" checklist-value="tab" ng-checked="setCheck(tab.id)">
                        {{tab.name}}
                    </md-checkbox>
                </md-input-container>
```

controller:

```
$scope.setCheck = function (id) {
        var alltabs = $scope.allTabs;
        for (var i = 0; i < alltabs.length; i++) {
            if (alltabs[i].id == id)
                return true
            return false
        }
    }
```

is there a way to allow this in angular?

Comment: Put your `return false` statement outside the `for`-loop. Currently it always returns false if the **first** `alltabs` element isn't the current checkbox

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `for`-loop is wrong. Put your `return false` statement outside the `for`-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < alltabs.length; i++) {
    if (alltabs[i].id == id)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Secondly, if you want to be able to check/uncheck the checkboxes, you should not use `ng-checked`. This directive reads every digest if the checkbox should be checked and behaves accordingly (see [the note in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)).

If you're using `ng-model` (or in this case `checklist-model`) you can just remove the `ng-checked`, because the `checklist-model` will just check the array for the already checked tabs.

Comment: Yes,  thought that too, but that doesn't happen

Comment: What solution you suggest?

Comment: F.Y.I. [Array's `some()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a clean way to do that looped check.